# adjust output from normalization?

Tags: normalization

I've trained a neural network network that given a minmax normalized input, provides a minmax normalized output.

this might be late, but is it possible from a minmax normalized output to create the actual output, given you know the actual min and max value?

so an unormalized output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just rearrange the formula for finding the normalised value. Where $x_i$ is the original attribute, and $z_i$ is the normalised value:

$$ 
\begin{align}
  z_i &= \frac{x_i - min(x)}{max(x) - min(x)} \\
  x_i &= z_i(max(x) - min(x)) + min(x) 
\end{align}
$$